# Disable Download video from facebook video player

Tags: php, facebook, video-streaming

I have posted a video using meta tags and it plays, but I want to remove the download option from the right click context menu of that player. Is this possible?

I have used flash player and following code we have used to share videos on facebook -

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" >
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP ID" />
<meta property="og:url" content="URL"/>
<meta property="og:link" content="Detail Link"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="Image URL"/>   
<meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video"/>
<meta property="og:video:url" content="Video URL"/>
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="Video Secure URL"/>
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640"/>
<meta property="og:video:height" content="480"/>
<meta name="video_type" content="video/mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="video tag"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean from the Facebook player, or do you use your own (flash) player? Do you have an example page that people can share to test?

Comment: btw if we want to download that video....how can we do that?